# sorting excel column as number with text

Tags: excel, sorting

I have data like this on column A 
[image: I have data like this on column a]

**When I'm going to sort column a by Value (A-Z) It's Sort like below**

[image: When I'm going to sort column a by Value (A-Z) It's Sort like below]

But I want to Sort this Column By

1-MBM Admission Test-2010 (14th Batch)-175.csv

2-MBM Admission Test 2012 (16th Batch)-172.csv

3-MBM Admission Test 2011 (15th Batch)-174.csv

How Can I do this? I have searched many solution but none of it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand that text sorts different to numbers. If you have text that starts with a number, it will still sort as text. And for text sort, the order is 1,11,19,2,20 etc.That means, text is sorted strictly by each character after the other. The first sort will be for the first character, so all items with a 1 as the first character come first. Then the next character is evaluated. A "-" sign will be sorted after any number, so the "1-" comes after the "10" and even after the "19".

To achieve the sort order you describe you will need to change the text and pad the numbers with leading zeroes, like

```
001-Some text
002-Some text
010-Some text
100-Some Text
```

Answer (score 1):

right click the 1st row of the column then hover over "filter" select "Filter by selected cell value" then click drop down and tadaaa ...Sort in Order...

[image: Do like this]
[image: woalaaa !!]